# C#: unsafe pointer to empty array is null?

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

In an `unsafe` block, I'm trying to get a pointer to a `byte` array. But I get different results depending on the declared size of the array:

```
unsafe {

    byte[] bytes;

    bytes = new byte[1];
    fixed(void* pBytes = bytes)
    {
        ((int)pBytes).Dump(); //prints e.g. 41797644
    }

    bytes = new byte[0];
    fixed(void* pBytes = bytes)
    {
        ((int)pBytes).Dump(); //prints 0 ?!
    }
}
```

If I open the immediate window and type `&bytes`, I get the actual addresses of the byte arrays, including the case with the empty array.

Why doesn't the `fixed` unmanaged pointer work the same?

UPDATE:

Here's the same code and what I get from the immediate window:

```
unsafe {
    byte[] bytes;
    bytes = new byte[1];
    fixed(void* pBytes = bytes)
    {
                       // bytes => 
                       // {byte[1]}
                       //    [0]: 0
                       //
                       // &bytes
                       // 0x0601c34c               //the address of the variable
                       //    bytes: 0x027dc804     //the address of the array
                       //
                       // pBytes
                       // 0x027dc80c               // notice pBytes == (&bytes + 8)
                       //     *pBytes: 0
    }

    bytes = new byte[0];
    fixed(void* pBytes = bytes)
    {
                       // bytes => 
                       // {byte[0]}
                       //
                       // &bytes
                       // 0x0601c34c               //same address of the variable, ofc
                       //    bytes: 0x02aa7ad4     //different address of (new) array 
                       //
                       // pBytes
                       // 0x00000000               // BOINK
                       //     *pBytes: Cannot dereference 'pBytes'. 
                       //              The pointer is not valid.
    }
}
```

The 8-byte difference between the address of the array object (&bytes) and the array pointer is explained by the object's header.

The array representation in memory is:

```
     type id  size     elem 0   elem1    ...
----|--------|--------|--------|--------|...
    ^ 4Bytes   4Bytes ^
    |                 `--< pBytes
    `--< &bytes
```

The unsafe pointer actually points to the start of, well, *actual* data (i.e. what would be marshalled to an unmanaged context)

**Is there a way I could get, in code, the actual address of the empty array?**

FWIW, I actually need that to be able to get to the array's header, to modify the array's runtime-type on the fly.

Comment: _to modify the array's runtime-type on the fly_ - why not make a new array? Seems your approach could break type-safety for the whole process.

Comment: I knew I'd get yelled at for that :) Ok, the use-case is converting between byte[] and sbyte[] on the fly. (Which almost works with casting, but methods like Array.Copy() don't like mixing of sbyte and byte arrays

Comment: This question looks like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Rakkun Possibly, but I  think it's still an interesting question and I'm hoping to get some insight from it.

Comment: Henk is correct: under no circumstances should you be messing with the internal state of the objects like this. Rather than *messing around with internal state that could crash the entire runtime* in order to *fake out Array.Copy* why not just write your own Array.Copy that allows copying `byte` to `sbyte`?

Comment: @EricLippert That's certainly an interesting tangent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why doesn't the fixed unmanaged pointer work the same?

That's a strange question. Why do you believe it should?

The contract is: when you fix an array with n elements where n > 0 you get a pointer to a buffer from which you can read and write n elements.

Now, When n is zero, null is *a pointer to a buffer from which you can read and write zero elements*, so as it turns out, that contract is actually met for the case where n is zero. **The C# language is not required to do so.** The specification says

> The behavior of the fixed statement is implementation-defined if the array expression is null or if the array has zero elements.

So the implementation would be entirely within its rights to, say, throw an exception in your program. The meaning of your program is actually not defined at all by the C# language specification.

You're trying to use `fixed` off-label in order to do something incredibly dangerous and wrong. Don't do that. You should use `fixed` on an array for one thing only: to obtain a pointer to a buffer of n elements that you can read and write.

> Is there a way I could get, in code, the actual address of the empty array?

Yes. Pin manually with a `GCHandle`.

Pinning a managed object in order to obtain its address is almost always dangerous and wrong.

> I need that to be able to get to the array's header, to modify the array's runtime-type on the fly.

That's always dangerous and wrong. Don't do that under any circumstances.

Comment: `+1` for the sheer amount of times you said *dangerous and wrong*.

Comment: Just out of curiousity is there any CIL/CLR references for the mentioned contract? I would love to read more into how pointers are handled by the CLR.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: I'm just trying to be clear that what the OP is doing here is **dangerous and wrong**.

Comment: @Romoku: Actually the situation is considerably worse than I implied by my text, which I shall fix up. I refer you to the C# 4.0 specification section 18.6, which states "The behavior of the fixed statement is implementation-defined if the array expression is null or if the array has zero elements."

Comment: @Romoku googling for the quote from the spec, I found [the docs on "`fixed` statement"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664784(v=vs.71).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Walking the *dangerous and wrong* path comes with its benefits, like better understanding what's really under the hood. This was my first exposure to non-trivial `unsafe` code, and it feels great knowing *what* can be done with it *and why it shouldn't be done*. That being said, I fixed the problem at hand (treating incoming `sbyte[]` arrays as `byte[]` arrays) using `Buffer.BlockCopy()` instead of `Array.Copy()`.

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu You can cast between `byte[]` and `sbyte[]` thanks to array variance. No copies or unsafe code required. But you need to insert a cast to `object` in between, because C# doesn't allow this conversion but the CLR does. This doesn't change the arrays runtime type, but it allows you to assign it to a `byte[]` variable.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Here's where that fails: 1. Try this: `var b = new byte[]{255}; var sb = (sbyte[])(object)b;sb.GetType();` -> prints `System.Byte[]`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos (cont'd) 2. `var sb2 = new sbyte[1];
Array.Copy(sb2,0,sb,0,1);` -> throws `ArrayTypeMismatchException` (Source array type cannot be assigned to destination array type.)

Comment: @CodesInChaos -> the "problem" is, the array is only cast "at compile-time", this doesn't change its runtime type - and methods like `Array.Copy` check that. My question was part of a big hack to get the *actual, runtime* type of the array to change (!) - and it works (on *my* machine, using the .NET and tooling *du jour*). It was quite an interesting experiment, but in the end I went the safe way and dispensed of it

Answer (score 1):

The way to get the address is to make a [`GCHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx).

See [GCHandle to get address(pointer) of .net object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097026/gchandle-to-get-addresspointer-of-net-object)

```
GCHandle handle;
IntPtr ptr;
byte[] bytes;

bytes = new byte[1];
handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);

ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
ptr.ToInt32().Dump(); // Prints 239580124

handle.Free();

unsafe {
    fixed(void* pBytes = bytes)
    {
        ((int)pBytes).Dump(); //prints 239580124
    }
}

bytes = new byte[0];
handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);

ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
ptr.ToInt32().Dump(); // Prints 239609660

handle.Free();

unsafe {
    fixed(void* pBytes = bytes)
    {
        ((int)pBytes).Dump(); //prints 0
    }
}
```

See [Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17091802/580951) for why it works like this.

Comment: +! Interesting. This answers the *how*, but not the *why* (regarding  the null pointer). It appears that the assignment operation `void* pBytes = bytes` is not just  dumb pointer arithmetic; it involves some logic.

Comment: I don't know the semantics of how the CLR handles pointers, so that would be left to someone with more knowledge.