# Make only one method of array of any kind to IntPtr

Tags: c#

Having a method to convert `double[] d` to `IntPtr` like:

```
public static IntPtr DoubleArrayToIntPtr(double[] d)
{
   IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(sizeof(double) * d.Length);
   Marshal.Copy(d, 0, p, d.Length);
   return p;
}
```

What would be the best way to make `int[]`, `float[]`, etc. I was thinking on making one method for each type like adding int[]:

```
public static IntPtr IntArrayToIntPtr(int[] d)
{
   IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(sizeof(int) * d.Length);
   Marshal.Copy(d, 0, p, d.Length);
   return p;
}
```

**1.** Could this method be generalized, if so how?

**2.** Is it possible to get pointer in only one line of code (As Marshal is void method)?

Comment: what do you need the intptr for - that determines how it would be marshalled.

Comment: Do you actually want a copy, or just a [pointer to a pinned array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4097057/11683)?

Comment: Text Transformation Templates Toolkit. T4 for short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach would be to make an extension class that did this for you, for each type. You cannot make it generic as `Marshal.Copy()` does not support a generic type. So you will have to duplicate your method for each type `byte`, `char`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, etc. However, you can make a generic helper method for determining your size to `Marshsal`.

Something like below could be useful to you:

```
public static class MarshalExtender
{
    public static IntPtr CopyToCoTaskMem(this byte[] array)
    {
        var ptr = AllocArrayCoTaskMem(array);

        Marshal.Copy(array, 0, ptr, array.Length);
        return ptr;
    }

    // Copy the above method and replace types as needed (int, double, etc).

    // Helper method for allocating bytes with generic arrays.
    static IntPtr AllocArrayCoTaskMem<T>(T[] array)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var size = Marshal.SizeOf(type) * array.Length;
        return Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size);
    }
}
```

The main benefit is in your code you could easily do something like:

```
var myArray = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... }
var ptr = myArray.CopyToCoTaskMem();
```

**NOTE:** Just be sure to call `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem()` when you are done with it! I would recommend your extension method returning an `IDisposable` object so you can wrap it in a `using` block.

For example:

```
public sealed class CoTaskMemoryHandle : IDisposable
{
    bool isDisposed;
    readonly IntPtr handle;

    public IntPtr Handle { get { return handle; } }

    public CoTaskMemoryHandle(IntPtr handle)
    {
        this.handle = handle;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        OnDispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    void OnDispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (isDisposed) return;

        if (isDisposing)
        {
            if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(handle);
        }

        isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

Then your modified extension class method:

```
public static CoTaskMemoryHandle CopyToCoTaskMem(this byte[] array)
{
    var ptr = AllocArrayCoTaskMem(array);

    Marshal.Copy(array, 0, ptr, array.Length);
    return new CoTaskMemoryHandle(ptr);
}
```

This way you can safely encapsulate the `Alloc`/`Free` balancing:

```
using(myArray.CopyToCoTaskMem())
{
   // Do something here..
}
```

Comment: I would recommend inheriting [`SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safehandlezeroorminusoneisinvalid.aspx) instead of `IDisposable`.

Comment: Yes! I was just thinking of this!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, yes, it could be generalized:

```
public static IntPtr ArrayToIntPtr<T>(T[] d) where T : struct
{
     var arrayType = typeof(T);
     IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)) * d.Length);
     if (arrayType == typeof(int))
     {
          Marshal.Copy((int[])(object)d, 0, p, d.Length);
     }
     //else if ....other types you want to handle
     return p;
}
```

I added a type constraint of struct, which limits you to value types (shorts, doubles, ints, structs). You'll obviously need to take care with what you pass in there (like if you pass in a struct).

To address your second question, no, I don't think you can cut that down to a single line, and even if you could, you probably wouldn't want to for readability.

**EDIT**
I've fixed issues identified by SiLo in the comments, but this code is now very ugly and I can't say I would recommend this approach. It obviously involves a lot of type checks and boxing to get at the right type. In fact, I'd personally recommend following Silo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20621398/1346943) over mine, although I've at least shown you can do this in a quasi-generic way, although certainly breaking the spirit of generics in the first place.

Comment: Several issues with this. First you will get a warning for `sizeof` needing to be used in an **unsafe** context which is not recommended. `Marshal.SizeOf()` should be used instead. Even still, `Marshal.Copy` does not support generic arguments and this will not work.

Comment: @SiLo that's what I get for writing code in SO and not in an actual C# editor

Comment: No problem, I tend to do that sometimes so I understand. I was curious about this so I started up VS to see. Unfortunately, it is not this simple. :( Seems like separate overloads would be required but they could be fairly small methods.